# Send method to all properties (which respond to it)

Tags: ios, dynamic, properties

Say you have a class, with various properties

```
@interface Tank : UIViewController

@property (strong) Part *part;
@property (strong) Wheel *wheel;
@property (strong) Radar *radar;

@property (strong) IBOutlet UIView *blah;
@property (strong) IBOutlet UILabel *blah;
@property (strong) IBOutlet UIView *blah;

@end
```

In the example, all of Part, Wheel, Radar are `UIExcitingView`

UIExcitingView responds to `specialSetup`

Note that, obviously in the specific class I could use an array, say, to send specialSetup to each of those items.

However, I want to subclass UIViewController to UISuperViewController,

So that it dopes this automatically, every time.

Simply, at setup time UISuperViewController should do like this ...

```
for each property in the class
if it responds to specialSetup
send specialSetup to it
```

alternately,

```
for each property in the class
if it is of class UIExcitingView
send specialSetup to it
```

So, how do you iterate over all properties, and check if it is a `UIExcitingView`?

Comment: would not be easier to collect the _objects_ into an array, and iterate through the items of the array? there must be a very good reason of why you really want to operate the class's properties in runtime, dynamically...

Comment: HI @holex.  I couldn't have been more clear: I'm making a subclass that automatically does it, every time, for all such classes.  It's just a normal OO approach.

Comment: you were clear, that is true, but that is definitely not a normal approach in OO (in spite of it is doable), and there must be a very particular reason to operate with the class's properties in runtime like this. if that is part of the standard design pattern, then it would be a horrible idea. that is what I'm saying only.

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying. In general one should be careful at runtime :)

Answer (score 3):

Use  this method and iterate through all the properties and check whether they respond to ur desired method.

```
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &outCount);
```

Use this to get the property name

```
objc_property_t property = properties[i];
 const char *propName = property_getName(property);
```

Use this  to check whether it responds to  ur method.

```
[[self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:propName]] respondsToSelector:@selector(methodName)];
```

Use this to send message if the property responds to it.

```
[[self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:propName]]  performSelector:@selector(methodName)];
```